# Need to add a loop to exit or repeat in C++

Tags: c++

I want to make a code that asks user for input either to quit or repeat. I am not getting the desired output.

```
int main()
{
    char yes,yn;
    do
    {
        cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
        while(yn != 'y' || yn != 'Y' || yn != 'n' || yn != 'N')
        {
            cout<<"enter (Y/N): ";
            cin>>yes;
            yn = yes;
        }
    }while(yn == 'y' || yn == 'Y');
}
```

Program asks for user input, when I input "Y,y,N or n", it should get out of the loop and then decide whether exit or repeat. But it isn't getting out of the loop and asking me for input again and again. I am not getting what is stopping to get out of the loop.

Comment: yn is not initialized, a do...while could work better in the inner loop. And the outer loop seems useless at that point..

Comment: Why two loops. I think one loop will suffice your need.... please reconsider your coding...inner loop is not required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for help. I have got what i wanted from all of you. Here is the final code running successfully. I have improved my code using suggestion from everyone of yours opinion.

```
int main()
{
    char yes,yn;
    do
    {
        .......... (main content of program, do things here.)
         do
        {
            cout<<"Do again? (Y/N):";
            cin>>yes;
            yn = toupper(yes);
            if(yn!='N' && yn != 'Y')
            {
                cout<<"Invalid selection"<<endl;
            }
            if(yn=='N' || yn == 'Y')
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        while(true);
    }
    while(yn == 'Y');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I didn't test, but your issue seems to be here:

```
while(yn != 'y' || yn != 'Y' || yn != 'n' || yn != 'N')
```

This condition is always true (yet shouldn't). It should be :

```
while(yn != 'y' && yn != 'Y' && yn != 'n' && yn != 'N')
```

or

```
while(!(yn == 'y' || yn == 'Y' || yn == 'n' || yn == 'N'))
```

Moreover, `yn` isn't initiliazed, you may want to do a `do { ... } while(...);` again.

Comment: yes. issue was there. I have replaced || with &&. Getting more progress.

Answer (score 1):

```
while(yn != 'y' || yn != 'Y' || yn != 'n' || yn != 'N')
```

Is always true. It should be

```
while(yn != 'y' && yn != 'Y' && yn != 'n' && yn != 'N')
```

Answer (score 1):

I think do while loop is all you need for the execution...

```
    int main()
{
    char yes,yn;
    do
    {
        cout << "Hello world!" << endl;       
            cout<<"enter (Y/N): ";
            cin>>yes;
            yn = yes;
       if(yn=='N'||yn=='n')
       {
          break;  
       }

    }while(true);
}
```

your loop does not exit becuse your while loop is always true..

```
while(yn != 'y' || yn != 'Y' || yn != 'n' || yn != 'N')
```

Now I have added a break statement in your loop on a if condition and changed the do while condition
in this case it will run the loop on any condition and will exit the loop only when the user enter n or N

Comment: this will check for "y and Y". If I enter anything besides "y,Y,n or N" it will exit the loop. I specifically want only these four letter to perform action.

Comment: @Krups wht do you want to perform if user entered a different value other than these 4

Comment: if by mistake user enters different character than it will exit the program. that I don't want it.

Comment: @Krups I have made some changes in the code now it will exit only when the user enters N or n

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, this expression:

```
(yn != 'y' || yn != 'Y' || yn != 'n' || yn != 'N')
```

is always true, as `yn` is always not equal to one of those things.

```
(yn != 'y' && yn != 'Y' && yn != 'n' && yn != 'N')
```

is probably what you meant.

Secondly, your life would be easier if you did

```
 yes = toupper (yes);
```

(i.e. put it in upper case), then you'd only have to look for one thing.

Thirdly, and most seriously, your inner `while` examines the value of `yes` before it's been initialized. Either use a `do` `while()` construct, or intialize the value to something before the loop.

Fourthly, it's not clear what you are trying do to here. Do you really need two loops at all?

Comment: one loop is to check that the input character is among those 4(now I have added toupper. in that case between 2 cases.) no other characters are allowed. second loop to check between y and n.

Comment: but better solutions are welcomed as long as they carry these two conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You did not initialize variable `yn`. So this statement

```
while(yn != 'y' || yn != 'Y' || yn != 'n' || yn != 'N')
```

has no sense and in fact it is unnecessary.
Try the following code

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    char yes_no;

    do
    {
        std::cout << "\nHello world!" << std::endl;

        std::cout<< "Do you want to repeat? (enter Y/N): ";
        std::cin >> yes_no;
    } while ( yes_no == 'y' || yes_no == 'Y' );
}
```